# Drawing performance with Swift in Xcode for iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, drawing, lines

I have a function for drawing lines, edited below. It seems to work fine in the simulator, however there are performance issues, lines drawn slowly, when running on both an older iPhone (2011) and a newer iPad (2014). I believe this issue is due to creating a new **CGContext** for every **touchesMoved** event received.

How can I, for example, call **let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()** once when **touchesBegan**? (i.e. how can I make **context** a public variable that can be called once?)

Any other tips for improving the performance would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    autoreleasepool {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.frame.size, false, 0.0)

    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    ...
    ...
    ...

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    }

}
```

Comment: Could you not just make context a class level variable?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Could you briefly explain what you mean by making the 'context' as a 'class level variable'? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not execute drawing code in touchesMoved. You should store whatever you need to update your drawing (probably touch location), then call `setNeedsDisplay`. That will force a call to `drawRect:` which would contain all of your drawing code. You do not need to create a context, just use `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()`.

Here is a contrived UIView subclass example that draws a red circle underneath the latest touch point.

```
class DrawView: UIView {

  let circleSize:CGFloat = 50.0
  var lastTouchPoint:CGPoint?

  override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    lastTouchPoint = touches.first?.locationInView(self)
    self.setNeedsDisplay()
  }

  override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    lastTouchPoint = touches.first?.locationInView(self)
    self.setNeedsDisplay()
  }

  override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    if let touchPoint = lastTouchPoint {
      let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
      CGContextSetRGBFillColor (context, 1, 0, 0, 1);
      CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, CGRectMake(touchPoint.x - circleSize/2.0, touchPoint.y - circleSize/2.0, circleSize , circleSize))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd put it more strongly. **DO NOT TRY TO DRAW in touchesMoved**. The only time you should draw is in drawRect, unless you are creating an offscreen context for rendering to an image. Other than that, you should set things up and call setNeedsDisplay. That triggers a call to your drawRect method. When drawRect is called the graphics context is set up appropriately and you just draw to the current context.

Comment: Thanks. So to clarify, something like as follows?

override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
     setNeedsDisplay()
}

override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
     //drawing code goes here
}

On a side note, when adjusting the scale factor of the beginimagecontext, the performance is affected. When the scale is 1.0, everything works super fast, however, then the scale factor is 0.0, 2.0 or 3.0 for retina displays, the performance is terrible with lots of lagging while drawing.

**UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.frame.size, false, 0.0)**

Comment: I added an example. Just as you shouldn't for every call to touchesMoved, do not create a new context for every call to drawRect.

Comment: Thank you all for your efforts looking into this. I now understand to keep drawing contained to drawRect.